# Ionic 3 Combining Observables

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable, ionic3

I am trying to create an observable stream that will listen to a my firebase database and also changes in location. Here is what I am working with.

In my service I create a Subject that I change location from: 
`private location: Subject<{ lat: number, lng: number }> = new Subject();`
Then I have a function returning these combined observables:

```
  getBusinessData() {
    return Observable.combineLatest(this.db.list(`${this.root}`), this.location, (x, y) => ({ x, y })).map(data => {
      return data.x;
    });
  }
```

As shown I am combine the detect of changes in my database as well as when I change locations.From one page on load I cam calling this function

```
 this.b = this.provider.getBusinessData()
 this.provider.changeLocation({ lat: 41.059481, lng: -82.023820 });

<ion-item *ngFor="let business of b | async"  >
  <h1> {{business.name}}</h1>
</ion-item>
```

To change locations I call this function in my provider

```
  changeLocation(newLocation: { lat: number, lng: number }) {        
      this.location.next(newLocation)
  }
```

I want to combine these because if I change location I want my subscriptions to emit there values again where map the data from the database based on the new location. My Question is if anyone knows how I can achieve this. Possibly I need to set a default value to my locations so the combined observables will emit there value when first subscribed. Maybe I need to do something completely different. I've been trying to get this to work with no luck if anyone has any ideas it will be a huge help. Thank you!